# What is the meaning of endAllStagingAnimators on 0x55a49d6cd0 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x55a46650d0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-animation

In android i get this in logcat while i am running my app. My app is turn based game like tic tac toe. There are 2 animation (1 YTransition & other rotate) on every click to update the grid board. There are no problems but when I run app for the first time then these animations appears but when I click on play again button then these animations doesn't show. But if go back to main screen and click on new game then again for the first time animations show. If this is related to the message that is shown in logcat ?