# endAllStagingAnimators explanation

Tags: java, android, android-logcat

Today I noticed the following in my logcat:

`D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa2c70600 (CardView) with handle 0xa2c9d350`

First of all, I haven't noticed any errors when running the application, but I did some research and couldn't find anything about this. There is also a few questions about this with no answers:

- [endAllStagingAnimators on RippleEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38173552/5550161)
- [what is endAllStagingAnimators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43335842/5550161)
- [endAllStagingAnimators on CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34101135/5550161)

The name `endAllStagingAnimators` kind of says what it is, "ending all animators". But like I said, I can't find any information about this.

So **my question is**:

What is **endAllStagingAnimators**, should I be worried about it and where can I get more information about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This message is related to RippleEffect Animation. It is an internal message which must have been logged after ripple effect has finished (indicating that all staged animators of ripple effect are successfully removed from CardView).
2. This is not an error message and thus won't affect you in any way. It is internal debug message( **D/** OpenGLRenderer). Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616296/meaning-of-these-logcat-messages/41616358#41616358)